# Unable to create EC2 instance from Own AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an AMI from a running Ubuntu16.4 EC2 instance, and then tried to create a new EC2 instance out of the new AMI. However, the status check of the new EC2 instance shows "1/2 status check", as System check passed but Instance Status Checks failed.

There is not specific information as regard to what is wrong. I rebooted the instance multiple times without any luck. I am unable to ssh to the instance as putty shows "timeout".

Did anyone step into the same situation before? Any advise that can let me move forward?

Comment: You might need to do little bit more digging to find out what is the root cause for failure. "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html"

Comment: According to [Status Checks for Your Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html), it might be related to kernel or network selection.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried production VPC/subnet but still had no luck. I checked system log in the console but nothing useful to me.